# Laravel модель отношения между тремя таблицами

Tags: laravel

Помогите пожалуйста правильно сделать запрос с учетом отношений между таблицами. Есть 4 таблицы:

Customers

id
company

Dishes

id

dish_name

Orders

customer_id

amount

Orders_Dishes

order_id

dish_id

Между таблицами установленны связи hasMany и belongsTo.

Сделал запрос, который выводит мне нужную информация:

$foods = Order::join('orders_dishes', 'orders.id', '=', 'orders_dishes.order_id')
->join('dishes', 'orders_dishes.dish_id', '=', 'dishes.id')
->join('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'orders.customer_id' )
->select('dishes.id', 'dishes.dish_name', 'orders_dishes.amount', 'customers.company')
->where('orders.id', '=', $order->id)
->get();

Вывод:

{
"id": 5,
"dish_name": "утка по-пекински",
"amount": 1,
"company": "ООО Компания ЭлектроВостокКазань"
}

В результате я получаю id заказа, название блюда, количество заказанных блюд, данные клиента, сделавшего заказ. Как мне рефакторить код и сделать запрос, с учетом отношений между таблицами. Мне нужно использовать директиву through или как, не могу понять, помогите.

Answer (score 0):

Если все нужные отношения уже подключены то это должно выглядеть как то так

```php
$foods = Order::with(['orders_dishes.dishes','customers'])-get();
```